# Pass flexible parameters PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have my webpage, where I have 10 rows, and in every rows is input field (checkbox). I want to create button with title 'Detail'. When I click on this button, my webpage open new page only with checked rows.

1. Task is, that I need to send every checkbox into detail button, and I don´t know, how much rows will be displayed (depend on database). I need to create function with input flexible parameters (name_array and value_array). But when I create this function, my arrays are empty. What I´m doing bad? Thank you for your response.

I dont have any form, I want to do that without form element.

This is my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id_netnum_5356963" netnum="5356963" />
```

And this is my button to detail:

```
<a href="!cpc2.pkg_fe_netnum_gui.p_detail_numbers">
  <button>
    <span class="btn-green-small btn-w130">Detail</span>
  </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use flexible parameter passing

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12303/concept.htm#1005765